# Power BI: How to add custom column when "append queries as new table"

Tags: powerbi, append

I followed the instructions on the [Microsoft web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries) to merge multiple tables into a single table or as they are called 'append queries to new table'.  It works.

The problem is if I add a new custom column to each table after importing the tables into Power BI, ex I add a column called 'Group' to each table and for Table1 I populate the column with 'GroupA' and Table2 with 'GroupB' etc, when I click 'append queries to new table' it only merges the original columns and ignores the custom column I added.

Is there a solution to merge the custom columns too?  These custom columns are identifiers so I need them.   Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: the append command will append the tables as they exist at that point. Just work the append command after you added all the custom columns to the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

[teylyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447970/teylyn) answered the question in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78177762/power-bi-how-to-add-custom-column-when-append-queries-as-new-table/78183120#comment137824650_78177762) posted on the question:

> the append command will append the tables as they exist at that point. Just work the append command after you added all the custom columns to the two tables.